# CarPlay setRootTemplate is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carplay

So now I am using

```
let listTemplate = CPListTemplate(title: "name", sections: sections)
        interfaceController?.setRootTemplate(listTemplate, animated: true)
```

to set the template but Xcode tells me this: `'setRootTemplate(_:animated:)' was deprecated in iOS 14.0`

What is the new way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [The New One With Completion In Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpinterfacecontroller/2968298-setroottemplate)

```
interfaceController?.setRootTemplate(listTemplate, animated: true,completion:nil)
```

You can also use the async version

```
Task {
  do {
      let listTemplate = CPListTemplate(title: "name", sections: sections)
      try await interfaceController.setRootTemplate(listTemplate, animated: true)
  }
  catch {
      print(error)
  }
}
```